# Should I #include in my library's namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a library that lives in its own namespace. Every file is wrapped by this namespace. When I use the standard library, should I include it into the global namespace or the one of my library? Moreover, what about library intern includes. Should they go inside or outside the namespace?

```
#include <vector> // This allows reuse

namespace library {
    #include <vector> // This would not leak anything
    #include "cart.h"
    using namespace std;

    class Train {
        vector<cart> carts;
    };
}
```

Including into the global namespace would make sense when the user needs vectors, too, so that the compiler doesn't need to integrate two versions of the standard library. On the other hand, including into the library's namespace makes sure that nothing leaks outside.

Comment: You can't do that reliably; the standard library code is meant to be in the `std` namespace, not the `library::std` namespace.  If there's any non-templated functions, the system library will provide the `std::non_templated_function` and not `library::std::non_templated_function`, so your code won't link.  If everything is a template, you may get away with it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That makes sense to me. What about library intern includes?

Comment: Don't do that, include files will be no longer self contained. Put all of your `#include <xxx>` statements at the very beginning of the file, and add `namespace`'s appropriately in each of your header files!

Comment: Your library's internal includes can be included inside the namespace if you want.  You might care to think about including them inside your own `internal` sub-namespace (`library::internal::…`).  Ensure you always include them inside the scope of your `namespace library { … }` brackets.  Alternatively, they could be standalone and inside your library namespace (since namespaces are extensible).  Either mechanism can be made to work; pick one and stick with it.  On the whole, I think standalone headers are 'better' (I agree with @πάντα ῥεῖ).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay, so I wrap every file with my standard namespace and put all includes globally. I think you could post your comment as an answer so I have something to accept! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applied 'common sense' suggests that you can't reliably include C++ standard headers inside your own namespace.  The standard library code is meant to be in the `std` namespace, not the `library::std` namespace. If there are any non-templated functions, the system library will provide `std::non_templated_function` and not `library::std::non_templated_function`, so your code won't link. If everything is a template, you may get away with it, but it is (unnecessarily) risky at best so don't do it.

Further (as noted by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633852/should-i-include-in-my-librarys-namespace/25634043?noredirect=1#comment40051442_25634043)), the C++11 standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011) standard explicitly says in §17.6.2.2 *Headers [using.headers]*:

> ¶3 A translation unit shall include a header only outside of any external declaration or definition, and shall
>   include the header lexically before the first reference in that translation unit to any of the entities declared
>   in that header.

This refers to a header from the C++ standard library, of course; it makes no such proscription for your own headers.

In theory, your library's internal headers could be included inside your `library` namespace if you want (but they shouldn't be — see below):

```
namespace library {
    #include "library/internal-header.h"
    …other declarations or definitions…
}
```

However (as [Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633852/should-i-include-in-my-librarys-namespace/25634043?noredirect=1#comment40051826_25634043)), doing so would mean that the internal header could not include any new standard headers, and yet it is quite plausible that an internal header would need to use some (extra) standard headers.

You might care to think about including them inside your own internal sub-namespace (for example, `library::internal`). If your internal headers do not contain their own `namespace library { … }` block, ensure you always include them inside the scope of your namespace `library { … }` brackets in the headers that include them, but note that the internal headers are no longer completely standalone.

Alternatively, and much more reliably, your library's internal headers <s>could</s> should be made standalone, with their contents defined inside your `library` namespace (since namespaces are extensible).

```
#include "library/internal-header.h"
namespace library {
    …other declarations or definitions…
}
```

where `"library/internal-header.h"` would contain:

```
namespace library {
    namespace internal {
        …internal declarations or definitions…
    }
}
```

where the `namespace internal {` and matching `}` are optional — and you might want a `using namespace library::internal;` directive as well.

Either mechanism could be made to work. On the whole, though, standalone headers are much the better (I agree with [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96) and his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633852/should-i-include-in-my-librarys-namespace#comment40050940_25633852) and Matt McNabb).

Comment: Copy and pasting your comment would have been fine, but your elaboration made the concept more clear to me. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that including standard library headers inside a namespace is explicitly banned by §17.6.2.2 [using.headers]/p3 ("A translation unit shall include a header only outside of any external declaration or definition").

Comment: @T.C. — Ah, thanks!  I'm not as familiar with the interstices of the C++11 standard as I am with the C11 standard.

Comment: The first suggestion is extremely risky, as `library/internal-header.h` might include a standard header.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Hmmm…Good point.  A pre-requisite for using the first technique would be that the internal headers could not include new standard library headers — which, in practice, makes it impractical. So, standalone headers are the way to go.